# Codeigniter form_dropdown issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I need a bit of help.

I have this in my view

```
$salutation = array(
        'Mr.' => 'Mr.',
        'Mrs.' => 'Mrs.',
        'Dr.' => 'Dr.',
        );    

    echo form_open('membership/update');

    echo form_dropdown('Salutation', $salutation, 'Mrs.');
```

The dropdown works in all but one fashion, it does not pre-select 'Mrs.'. How can I get that to work properly. According to the Codeigniter userguide, I have the proper syntax.

Comment: I thought maybe the trailing comma in the array would be a problem, but I've just plugged this into a CodeIgniter project of mine, and 'Mrs.' was auto-selected properly.

Comment: Sorry i did not notice that :)

Comment: so what is stopping it from working in mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you F5, this change will not appear in the form.  You need to hit enter next to the URL in your browser for these kind of changes to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Good News!

I got it to work. After cnanney said it worked for him, I checked the cache in firefox, for some reason it was old cache from a while ago, refreshing and deleting did not help. After a restart, things are good.

Thanks!